# WCF CustomBinding - Cannot obtain Metadata with custom authorization policy

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, binding, metadata

After solving my previous problem, I wanted to convert the netTcpBinding to a customBinding, which I managed succesfully. However, WcfTestClient (and normal client) give an error while trying to extract metadata when I put a custom authorization policy in place (it works fine without!).

My config:

```
<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="Sample.Tools.CustomAuthorizationPolicy, Sample" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
```

I've read on MSDN (here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wcf/thread/80a33bc6-0765-45f6-8af5-0a414a5cc40d) that this may be caused because a custom authorization manager is also required. I tried this and added the CustomAuthorizationManager as well (with CheckAccessCore always returning true), but it didn't work.

This is added in the config as:

```
    <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Sample.Tools.CustomAuthorizationManager, Sample">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="Sample.Tools.CustomAuthorizationPolicy, Sample" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
```

The rest of the config:

Binding:

```
<customBinding>
      <binding name="SampleBinding" receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
        <transactionFlow/>
        <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameForSslNegotiated" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
                <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
           </secureConversationBootstrap>                   
            <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
            <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
        </security>
        <binaryMessageEncoding/>
        <tcpTransport transferMode="Buffered" portSharingEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
```

Behavior:

```
<behavior name="SampleBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" />
        <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Sample.Tools.CustomAuthorizationManager, Sample">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="Sample.Tools.CustomAuthorizationPolicy, Sample" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="MySample" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Sample.Tools.CustomUserNameValidator, Sample" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
```

Services:

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="SampleBehavior"
    name="Sample.SampleService">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="customBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="SampleBinding"
              name="MyServiceEndpoint" 
              contract="Sample.ISampleService">
        <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexTcpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration=""
              name="MyServiceMexTcpBidingEndpoint" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:809/SampleService.svc" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
</services>
```

I'm pretty much stuck here and there is very little to find regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this nice post here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/86ed7974-97d4-4cc8-a965-542a3063aced

This fixed my issue, now I need to look into implementing a proper ServiceAuthorizationManager :)